# UIButton on UIScrollView can't work

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 180)];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(show)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 120.0, 30, 30);
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[self addSubview:myButton];
```

in this way the button works(call `show:`), but use `[myLabel addSubview:myButton];` the button doesn't work. not sure why?

----------------EDIT & SOLUTION------------
Thanks @KennyTM

UILabel by default doesn't handle any events. You need to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the label to `YES`.

Also you'd better not add a UIButton on the top of a UILabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel by default doesn't handle any events. You need to set the [`userInteractionEnabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW50) of the label to YES.

A button shouldn't be a subview of a label anyway, it's illogical. Make both of them subviews of a UIView.

Comment: Thank you, just think they are all subclasses of UIView.

Comment: @william: UILabel *is* a subclass of UIView, only that it explicitly turns off `userInteractionEnabled`.